ClickOnce GenerateApplicationManifest MSB3171 "...to load a program with an incorrect format" with native DLLs
I have the following simple project:
using ImageMagick;
using SkiaSharp;
using System;

namespace ConsoleApp1
{
    public class Program
    {
        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            MagickImageInfo info = new MagickImageInfo();
            info.Read("photo.jpg");

            Console.WriteLine($"Magick.NET: {info.Width}x{info.Height}px");

            var image = SKImage.FromEncodedData(@"photo.jpg");
            var bm = SKBitmap.FromImage(image);

            Console.WriteLine($"SkiaSharp: {bm.Width}x{bm.Height}px");
        }
    }
}

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<packages>
  <package id="Magick.NET.Core" version="14.2.0" targetFramework="net48" />
  <package id="Magick.NET-Q16-HDRI-x64" version="14.2.0" targetFramework="net48" />
  <package id="SkiaSharp" version="2.88.9" targetFramework="net48" />
  <package id="SkiaSharp.NativeAssets.macOS" version="2.88.9" targetFramework="net48" />
  <package id="SkiaSharp.NativeAssets.Win32" version="2.88.9" targetFramework="net48" />
  <package id="System.Buffers" version="4.5.1" targetFramework="net48" />
  <package id="System.Memory" version="4.5.5" targetFramework="net48" />
  <package id="System.Numerics.Vectors" version="4.5.0" targetFramework="net48" />
  <package id="System.Runtime.CompilerServices.Unsafe" version="4.5.3" targetFramework="net48" />
</packages>

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Project ToolsVersion="15.0" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003">
  <Import Project="$(MSBuildExtensionsPath)\$(MSBuildToolsVersion)\Microsoft.Common.props" Condition="Exists('$(MSBuildExtensionsPath)\$(MSBuildToolsVersion)\Microsoft.Common.props')" />
  <PropertyGroup>
    <Configuration Condition=" '$(Configuration)' == '' ">Debug</Configuration>
    <Platform Condition=" '$(Platform)' == '' ">AnyCPU</Platform>
    <ProjectGuid>{4965314B-8FB0-448D-93EF-804B3B4873BA}</ProjectGuid>
    <OutputType>Exe</OutputType>
    <RootNamespace>ConsoleApp1</RootNamespace>
    <AssemblyName>ConsoleApp1</AssemblyName>
    <TargetFrameworkVersion>v4.8</TargetFrameworkVersion>
    <FileAlignment>512</FileAlignment>
    <AutoGenerateBindingRedirects>true</AutoGenerateBindingRedirects>
    <Deterministic>true</Deterministic>
    <NuGetPackageImportStamp>
    </NuGetPackageImportStamp>
    <IsWebBootstrapper>false</IsWebBootstrapper>
    <PublishUrl>C:\path\to\published-clickonce-release\</PublishUrl>
    <Install>true</Install>
    <InstallFrom>Disk</InstallFrom>
    <UpdateEnabled>false</UpdateEnabled>
    <UpdateMode>Foreground</UpdateMode>
    <UpdateInterval>7</UpdateInterval>
    <UpdateIntervalUnits>Days</UpdateIntervalUnits>
    <UpdatePeriodically>false</UpdatePeriodically>
    <UpdateRequired>false</UpdateRequired>
    <MapFileExtensions>true</MapFileExtensions>
    <ApplicationRevision>8</ApplicationRevision>
    <ApplicationVersion>1.2.3.%2a</ApplicationVersion>
    <UseApplicationTrust>false</UseApplicationTrust>
    <PublishWizardCompleted>true</PublishWizardCompleted>
    <BootstrapperEnabled>true</BootstrapperEnabled>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <PropertyGroup Condition=" '$(Configuration)|$(Platform)' == 'Debug|AnyCPU' ">
    <PlatformTarget>AnyCPU</PlatformTarget>
    <DebugSymbols>true</DebugSymbols>
    <DebugType>full</DebugType>
    <Optimize>false</Optimize>
    <OutputPath>bin\Debug\</OutputPath>
    <DefineConstants>DEBUG;TRACE</DefineConstants>
    <ErrorReport>prompt</ErrorReport>
    <WarningLevel>4</WarningLevel>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <PropertyGroup Condition=" '$(Configuration)|$(Platform)' == 'Release|AnyCPU' ">
    <PlatformTarget>AnyCPU</PlatformTarget>
    <DebugType>pdbonly</DebugType>
    <Optimize>true</Optimize>
    <OutputPath>bin\Release\</OutputPath>
    <DefineConstants>TRACE</DefineConstants>
    <ErrorReport>prompt</ErrorReport>
    <WarningLevel>4</WarningLevel>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <PropertyGroup Condition="'$(Configuration)|$(Platform)' == 'Debug|x64'">
    <DebugSymbols>true</DebugSymbols>
    <OutputPath>bin\x64\Debug\</OutputPath>
    <DefineConstants>DEBUG;TRACE</DefineConstants>
    <DebugType>full</DebugType>
    <PlatformTarget>x64</PlatformTarget>
    <LangVersion>7.3</LangVersion>
    <ErrorReport>prompt</ErrorReport>
    <Prefer32Bit>true</Prefer32Bit>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <PropertyGroup Condition="'$(Configuration)|$(Platform)' == 'Release|x64'">
    <OutputPath>bin\x64\Release\</OutputPath>
    <DefineConstants>TRACE</DefineConstants>
    <Optimize>true</Optimize>
    <DebugType>pdbonly</DebugType>
    <PlatformTarget>x64</PlatformTarget>
    <LangVersion>7.3</LangVersion>
    <ErrorReport>prompt</ErrorReport>
    <Prefer32Bit>true</Prefer32Bit>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <PropertyGroup>
    <SignManifests>false</SignManifests>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <PropertyGroup>
    <ManifestTimestampUrl>http://timestamp.digicert.com</ManifestTimestampUrl>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <PropertyGroup>
    <SignAssembly>false</SignAssembly>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <PropertyGroup>
    <ManifestCertificateThumbprint>xxx</ManifestCertificateThumbprint>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetZone>LocalIntranet</TargetZone>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <PropertyGroup>
    <GenerateManifests>true</GenerateManifests>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <PropertyGroup />
  <PropertyGroup />
  <ItemGroup>
    <Reference Include="Magick.NET-Q16-HDRI-x64, Version=14.2.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=2004825badfa91ec, processorArchitecture=AMD64">
      <HintPath>..\packages\Magick.NET-Q16-HDRI-x64.14.2.0\lib\netstandard20\Magick.NET-Q16-HDRI-x64.dll</HintPath>
    </Reference>
    <Reference Include="Magick.NET.Core, Version=14.2.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=2004825badfa91ec, processorArchitecture=MSIL">
      <HintPath>..\packages\Magick.NET.Core.14.2.0\lib\netstandard20\Magick.NET.Core.dll</HintPath>
    </Reference>
    <Reference Include="SkiaSharp, Version=2.88.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=0738eb9f132ed756, processorArchitecture=MSIL">
      <HintPath>..\packages\SkiaSharp.2.88.9\lib\net462\SkiaSharp.dll</HintPath>
    </Reference>
    <Reference Include="System" />
    <Reference Include="System.Buffers, Version=4.0.3.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=cc7b13ffcd2ddd51, processorArchitecture=MSIL">
      <HintPath>..\packages\System.Buffers.4.5.1\lib\net461\System.Buffers.dll</HintPath>
    </Reference>
    <Reference Include="System.Core" />
    <Reference Include="System.Memory, Version=4.0.1.2, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=cc7b13ffcd2ddd51, processorArchitecture=MSIL">
      <HintPath>..\packages\System.Memory.4.5.5\lib\net461\System.Memory.dll</HintPath>
    </Reference>
    <Reference Include="System.Numerics" />
    <Reference Include="System.Numerics.Vectors, Version=4.1.4.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a, processorArchitecture=MSIL">
      <HintPath>..\packages\System.Numerics.Vectors.4.5.0\lib\net46\System.Numerics.Vectors.dll</HintPath>
    </Reference>
    <Reference Include="System.Runtime.CompilerServices.Unsafe, Version=4.0.4.1, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a, processorArchitecture=MSIL">
      <HintPath>..\packages\System.Runtime.CompilerServices.Unsafe.4.5.3\lib\net461\System.Runtime.CompilerServices.Unsafe.dll</HintPath>
    </Reference>
    <Reference Include="System.Xml.Linq" />
    <Reference Include="System.Data.DataSetExtensions" />
    <Reference Include="Microsoft.CSharp" />
    <Reference Include="System.Data" />
    <Reference Include="System.Net.Http" />
    <Reference Include="System.Xml" />
  </ItemGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <Compile Include="Program.cs" />
    <Compile Include="Properties\AssemblyInfo.cs" />
  </ItemGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <None Include="App.config" />
    <None Include="ClickOncePublishment.msbuild">
      <CopyToOutputDirectory>PreserveNewest</CopyToOutputDirectory>
    </None>
    <None Include="packages.config" />
  </ItemGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <Content Include="photo.jpg">
      <CopyToOutputDirectory>PreserveNewest</CopyToOutputDirectory>
    </Content>
  </ItemGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <BootstrapperPackage Include=".NETFramework,Version=v4.8">
      <Visible>False</Visible>
      <ProductName>Microsoft .NET Framework 4.8 %28x86 and x64%29</ProductName>
      <Install>true</Install>
    </BootstrapperPackage>
    <BootstrapperPackage Include="Microsoft.Net.Framework.3.5.SP1">
      <Visible>False</Visible>
      <ProductName>.NET Framework 3.5 SP1</ProductName>
      <Install>false</Install>
    </BootstrapperPackage>
  </ItemGroup>
  <Import Project="$(MSBuildToolsPath)\Microsoft.CSharp.targets" />
  <Import Project="..\packages\Magick.NET-Q16-HDRI-x64.14.2.0\build\netstandard20\Magick.NET-Q16-HDRI-x64.targets" Condition="Exists('..\packages\Magick.NET-Q16-HDRI-x64.14.2.0\build\netstandard20\Magick.NET-Q16-HDRI-x64.targets')" />
  <Target Name="EnsureNuGetPackageBuildImports" BeforeTargets="PrepareForBuild">
    <PropertyGroup>
      <ErrorText>This project references NuGet package(s) that are missing on this computer. Use NuGet Package Restore to download them.  For more information, see http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=322105. The missing file is {0}.</ErrorText>
    </PropertyGroup>
    <Error Condition="!Exists('..\packages\Magick.NET-Q16-HDRI-x64.14.2.0\build\netstandard20\Magick.NET-Q16-HDRI-x64.targets')" Text="$([System.String]::Format('$(ErrorText)', '..\packages\Magick.NET-Q16-HDRI-x64.14.2.0\build\netstandard20\Magick.NET-Q16-HDRI-x64.targets'))" />
    <Error Condition="!Exists('..\packages\SkiaSharp.NativeAssets.macOS.2.88.9\build\net462\SkiaSharp.NativeAssets.macOS.targets')" Text="$([System.String]::Format('$(ErrorText)', '..\packages\SkiaSharp.NativeAssets.macOS.2.88.9\build\net462\SkiaSharp.NativeAssets.macOS.targets'))" />
    <Error Condition="!Exists('..\packages\SkiaSharp.NativeAssets.Win32.2.88.9\build\net462\SkiaSharp.NativeAssets.Win32.targets')" Text="$([System.String]::Format('$(ErrorText)', '..\packages\SkiaSharp.NativeAssets.Win32.2.88.9\build\net462\SkiaSharp.NativeAssets.Win32.targets'))" />
  </Target>
  <Import Project="..\packages\SkiaSharp.NativeAssets.macOS.2.88.9\build\net462\SkiaSharp.NativeAssets.macOS.targets" Condition="Exists('..\packages\SkiaSharp.NativeAssets.macOS.2.88.9\build\net462\SkiaSharp.NativeAssets.macOS.targets')" />
  <Import Project="..\packages\SkiaSharp.NativeAssets.Win32.2.88.9\build\net462\SkiaSharp.NativeAssets.Win32.targets" Condition="Exists('..\packages\SkiaSharp.NativeAssets.Win32.2.88.9\build\net462\SkiaSharp.NativeAssets.Win32.targets')" />
</Project>

I can publish and sign this project successfully directly with Visual Studio 2022 using the Signing and Publish section in the project settings.
I have to automate that process with MSBuild tasks (without using Visualn Studio manually), especially the GenerateApplicationManifest step:
<Project DefaultTargets="GenerateManifests" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003">

  <PropertyGroup>
    <PackagedFilesDirectory>.</PackagedFilesDirectory>
    <ExecutableFilename>ConsoleApp1.exe</ExecutableFilename>
    <ConfigFilename>$(ExecutableFilename).config</ConfigFilename>
    <ApplicationManifestFilename>$(ExecutableFilename).manifest</ApplicationManifestFilename>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <EntryPoint Include="$(PackagedFilesDirectory)/$(ExecutableFilename)">
      <TargetPath>$(ExecutableFilename)</TargetPath>
    </EntryPoint>

    <!--<Dependency Include="$(PackagedFilesDirectory)\**\*.dll">
      --><!--Exclude="$(PackagedFilesDirectory)\Magick.Native-Q16-HDRI-x64.dll"--><!--
      <AssemblyType>Managed</AssemblyType>
      <DependencyType>Install</DependencyType>
      <TargetPath>%(RecursiveDir)%(Filename)%(Extension)</TargetPath>
    </Dependency>-->

    <Dependency Include="$(PackagedFilesDirectory)\Magick.Native-Q16-HDRI-x64.dll">
      <AssemblyType>Native</AssemblyType>
      <DependencyType>Install</DependencyType>
      <TargetPath>%(RecursiveDir)%(Filename)%(Extension)</TargetPath>
    </Dependency>

    <Dependency Include="$(PackagedFilesDirectory)/x64/libSkiaSharp.dll">
      <AssemblyType>Native</AssemblyType>
      <DependencyType>Install</DependencyType>
      <TargetPath>%(RecursiveDir)%(Filename)%(Extension)</TargetPath>
    </Dependency>

    <Dependency Include="$(PackagedFilesDirectory)\x86\libSkiaSharp.dll">
      <AssemblyType>Native</AssemblyType>
      <DependencyType>Install</DependencyType>
      <TargetPath>%(RecursiveDir)%(Filename)%(Extension)</TargetPath>
    </Dependency>

    <Dependency Include="$(PackagedFilesDirectory)\arm64\libSkiaSharp.dll">
      <AssemblyType>Native</AssemblyType>
      <DependencyType>Install</DependencyType>
      <TargetPath>%(RecursiveDir)%(Filename)%(Extension)</TargetPath>
    </Dependency>
  </ItemGroup>

  <Target Name="GenerateManifest">
    <!-- Create application manifest -->
    <GenerateApplicationManifest
      AssemblyName="ConsoleApp1.exe"
      AssemblyVersion="1.2.3.4"
      ConfigFile="ConsoleApp1.exe.config"
      Description="Console App Client"
      Dependencies="@(Dependency)"
      EntryPoint="@(EntryPoint)"
      Files="@(File)"
      OutputManifest="$(PackagedFilesDirectory)\$(ApplicationManifestFilename)"
      Platform="x64"
      Product="Console App Client"
      Publisher="ACME">
    </GenerateApplicationManifest>
  </Target>
</Project>

I learned that I can mark some DLLs as native inside of Dependency > AssemblyType.
Running a build works:
& "C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Enterprise\MSBuild\Current\Bin\MSBuild.exe" .\ConsoleApp1.sln "/p:Configuration=Release;Platform=x64;ApplicationVersion=1.2.3.4;Environment=Test" "/t:Restore;Clean;Rebuild" "/verbosity:minimal"
MSBuild-Version 17.12.6+db5f6012c für .NET Framework

  Wiederherzustellende Projekte werden ermittelt...
  ConsoleApp1 -> C:\...\ConsoleApp1\ConsoleApp1\bin\x64\Release\ConsoleApp1.exe

The MSBuild task to generate the manifest fails with an error MSB3171:
C:\...\ConsoleApp1\ConsoleApp1\bin\x64\Release> & "C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Enterprise\MSBuild\Current\Bin\MSBuild.exe" ./ClickOncePublishment.msbuild /t:GenerateManifest /property:AssemblyVersion=1.2.3.4 /property:DeploymentUrl=\\path\to\somewhere /property:Product="Acme-Client 64-bit" /property:Platform=x64

MSBuild-Version 17.12.6+db5f6012c für .NET Framework
Der Buildvorgang wurde am 26.11.2024 10:18:00 gestartet.

Die Erstellung des Projekts "C:\...\ConsoleApp1\ConsoleApp1\bin\x64\Release\ClickOncePublishment.msbuild" ist abgeschlossen, GenerateManifest Ziel(e)
-- FEHLER.

Fehler beim Buildvorgang.

"C:\...\ConsoleApp1\ConsoleApp1\bin\x64\Release\ClickOncePublishment.msbuild" (GenerateManifest Ziel) (1) ->
(GenerateManifest Ziel) ->
  C:\...\ConsoleApp1\ConsoleApp1\bin\x64\Release\ClickOncePublishment.msbuild(49,5): error MSB3171: Problem beim Generieren des Manifests. Die Datei oder Assembly "C:\...\ConsoleApp1\ConsoleApp1\bin\x64\Release\x64\libSkiaSharp.dll" oder eine Abhängigkeit davon wurde nicht gefunden. Es wurde versucht, eine Datei mit einem falschen Format zu laden.
  C:\...\ConsoleApp1\ConsoleApp1\bin\x64\Release\ClickOncePublishment.msbuild(49,5): error MSB3171: Problem beim Generieren des Manifests. Die Datei oder Assembly "C:\...\ConsoleApp1\ConsoleApp1\bin\x64\Release\Magick.Native-Q16-HDRI-x64.dll" oder eine Abhängigkeit davon wurde nicht gefunden. Es wurde versucht, eine Datei mit einem falschen Format zu laden.
  C:\...\ConsoleApp1\ConsoleApp1\bin\x64\Release\ClickOncePublishment.msbuild(49,5): error MSB3171: Problem beim Generieren des Manifests. Die Datei oder Assembly "C:\...\ConsoleApp1\ConsoleApp1\bin\x64\Release\arm64\libSkiaSharp.dll" oder eine Abhängigkeit davon wurde nicht gefunden. Es wurde versucht, eine Datei mit einem falschen Format zu laden.
  C:\...\ConsoleApp1\ConsoleApp1\bin\x64\Release\ClickOncePublishment.msbuild(49,5): error MSB3171: Problem beim Generieren des Manifests. Die Datei oder Assembly "C:\...\ConsoleApp1\ConsoleApp1\bin\x64\Release\x86\libSkiaSharp.dll" oder eine Abhängigkeit davon wurde nicht gefunden. Es wurde versucht, eine Datei mit einem falschen Format zu laden.

    0 Warnung(en)
    4 Fehler

(english: "Could not load file or assembly '*.dll' or one of its dependencies. An attempt was made to load a program with an incorrect format.")
I don't see a problem with a specific DLL, because it doesn't work with multiple different DLLs from different projects. The manifest generation works from Visual Studio. I am running the publishing step on the same machine as the MSBuild task. The DLL itself is not corrupted and does its job. Putting non-native DLLs into the manifest works. Marking the native DLLs as "Managed" does not work either.
The correct manifest would be:
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<asmv1:assembly xsi:schemaLocation="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1 assembly.adaptive.xsd" manifestVersion="1.0" xmlns:asmv1="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1" xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v2" xmlns:asmv2="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v2" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:co.v1="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:clickonce.v1" xmlns:asmv3="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v3" xmlns:dsig="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#" xmlns:co.v2="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:clickonce.v2">
  <asmv1:assemblyIdentity name="ConsoleApp1.exe" version="1.2.3.8" publicKeyToken="0000000000000000" language="neutral" processorArchitecture="amd64" type="win32" />
  <application />
  <entryPoint>
    <assemblyIdentity name="ConsoleApp1" version="1.0.0.0" language="neutral" processorArchitecture="amd64" />
    <commandLine file="ConsoleApp1.exe" parameters="" />
  </entryPoint>
  <trustInfo>
    <security>
      <applicationRequestMinimum>
        <PermissionSet version="1" class="System.Security.NamedPermissionSet" Name="LocalIntranet" Description="Default rights given to applications on the local intranet" ID="Custom" SameSite="site">
          <IPermission Read="USERNAME" version="1" class="System.Security.Permissions.EnvironmentPermission, mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" />
          <IPermission version="1" class="System.Security.Permissions.FileDialogPermission, mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" Unrestricted="true" />
          <IPermission version="1" Permanent="True" Expiry="9223372036854775807" UserQuota="9223372036854775807" Allowed="AssemblyIsolationByUser" class="System.Security.Permissions.IsolatedStorageFilePermission, mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" />
          <IPermission version="1" class="System.Security.Permissions.ReflectionPermission, mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" Flags="ReflectionEmit, RestrictedMemberAccess" />
          <IPermission version="1" class="System.Security.Permissions.SecurityPermission, mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" Flags="Assertion, Execution, BindingRedirects" />
          <IPermission version="1" class="System.Security.Permissions.UIPermission, mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" Unrestricted="true" />
          <IPermission version="1" class="System.Drawing.Printing.PrintingPermission, System.Drawing, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a" Level="DefaultPrinting" />
          <IPermission version="1" class="System.Security.Permissions.MediaPermission, WindowsBase, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" Audio="SafeAudio" Image="SafeImage" Video="SafeVideo" />
          <IPermission version="1" class="System.Security.Permissions.WebBrowserPermission, WindowsBase, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" Level="Safe" />
          <IPermission version="1" class="System.Net.DnsPermission, System, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" Unrestricted="true" />
          <IPermission version="1" class="System.Security.Permissions.TypeDescriptorPermission, System, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" Unrestricted="true" />
        </PermissionSet>
        <defaultAssemblyRequest permissionSetReference="Custom" />
      </applicationRequestMinimum>
    </security>
  </trustInfo>
  <dependency>
    <dependentAssembly dependencyType="preRequisite" allowDelayedBinding="true">
      <assemblyIdentity name="Microsoft.Windows.CommonLanguageRuntime" version="4.0.30319.0" />
    </dependentAssembly>
  </dependency>
  <dependency>
    <dependentAssembly dependencyType="install" allowDelayedBinding="true" codebase="ConsoleApp1.exe" size="4096">
      <assemblyIdentity name="ConsoleApp1" version="1.0.0.0" language="neutral" processorArchitecture="amd64" />
      <hash>
        <dsig:Transforms>
          <dsig:Transform Algorithm="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:HashTransforms.Identity" />
        </dsig:Transforms>
        <dsig:DigestMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#sha256" />
        <dsig:DigestValue>niWdT26A895yuMleQfgsBQBSOtv3UM5lth/uruyHma0=</dsig:DigestValue>
      </hash>
    </dependentAssembly>
  </dependency>
  <dependency>
    <dependentAssembly dependencyType="install" allowDelayedBinding="true" codebase="Magick.NET.Core.dll" size="1527592">
      <assemblyIdentity name="Magick.NET.Core" version="14.2.0.0" publicKeyToken="2004825BADFA91EC" language="neutral" processorArchitecture="msil" />
      <hash>
        <dsig:Transforms>
          <dsig:Transform Algorithm="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:HashTransforms.Identity" />
        </dsig:Transforms>
        <dsig:DigestMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#sha256" />
        <dsig:DigestValue>d0+KN/+66+8C8h1R7O0fU62zOnIL7ae8X4C1ACHMm1Y=</dsig:DigestValue>
      </hash>
    </dependentAssembly>
  </dependency>
  <dependency>
    <dependentAssembly dependencyType="install" allowDelayedBinding="true" codebase="Magick.NET-Q16-HDRI-x64.dll" size="811816">
      <assemblyIdentity name="Magick.NET-Q16-HDRI-x64" version="14.2.0.0" publicKeyToken="2004825BADFA91EC" language="neutral" processorArchitecture="amd64" />
      <hash>
        <dsig:Transforms>
          <dsig:Transform Algorithm="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:HashTransforms.Identity" />
        </dsig:Transforms>
        <dsig:DigestMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#sha256" />
        <dsig:DigestValue>32+oirD9Nbv+ozVgJIj6gYZ5Pz/ihw4gNdg4Wscgzm4=</dsig:DigestValue>
      </hash>
    </dependentAssembly>
  </dependency>
  <dependency>
    <dependentAssembly dependencyType="install" allowDelayedBinding="true" codebase="SkiaSharp.dll" size="806464">
      <assemblyIdentity name="SkiaSharp" version="2.88.0.0" publicKeyToken="0738EB9F132ED756" language="neutral" processorArchitecture="msil" />
      <hash>
        <dsig:Transforms>
          <dsig:Transform Algorithm="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:HashTransforms.Identity" />
        </dsig:Transforms>
        <dsig:DigestMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#sha256" />
        <dsig:DigestValue>5ww8h2/H/LM6NXOEMQdkkOrkfTSBM7rQgI1qv1pxYFY=</dsig:DigestValue>
      </hash>
    </dependentAssembly>
  </dependency>

...

</asmv1:assembly>


The native DLL has to probably be marked as a file, instead of a dependency.
